# How do I convert a CSV file to an RGB image using python

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library, genfromtxt

I'm trying to convert a csv file to an RGB file as follows:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
from numpy import genfromtxt

g = open('myFile.csv','r')
temp = genfromtxt(g, delimiter = ',')
im = Image.fromarray(temp).convert('RGB')
pix = im.load()
rows, cols = im.size
for x in range(cols):
    for y in range(rows):
        print str(x) + " " + str(y)
        pix[x,y] = (int(temp[x,y] // 256 // 256 % 256),int(temp[x,y] // 256 % 256),int(temp[x,y] % 256))
im.save(g.name[0:-4] + '.jpeg')
```

The issue is that the second last line is giving me a "IndexError: image index out of range". when I print out x and y I see that it happens whenever either of them reaches 5 which is the width of my file, but not the height, no matter how I play with it, whether x or y reaches 5, it throws an error and that's what I'm not figuring out. Any better implementations are also welcome.

Comment: Perhaps im.size is really cols, rows, not rows, cols?

Comment: @Zdar. Not sure about pix, which is not a numpy array as far as I know, but temp is definitely indexed backwards

Comment: @MadPhysicist , Good call, but I've been trying to swap things around, do minus one whatever, it doesn't matter, when either x or y reaches 5, game over.

Comment: Because half of your induces are backwards and half aren't.

Comment: @Mad Physicist, Indexed backwards? You mean temp[y,x] instead of temp[x,y]?

Comment: Yes, and also, re-read the pillow docs with reference to the other comments here.

Comment: @Mad Physicist, Thanks, I did what you said and it works, I'll post the solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case anyone wants the working algorithm, here goes:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
from numpy import genfromtxt

g = open('myFile.csv','r')
temp = genfromtxt(g, delimiter = ',')
im = Image.fromarray(temp).convert('RGB')
pix = im.load()
rows, cols = im.size
for x in range(cols):
    for y in range(rows):
        print str(x) + " " + str(y)
        pix[x,y] = (int(temp[y,x] // 256 // 256 % 256),int(temp[y,x] // 256  % 256),int(temp[y,x] % 256))
im.save(g.name[0:-4] + '.jpeg')
```

It was just a matter of changing temp[x,y] with temp[y,x] and swapping cols and rows.

Comment: No idea if you'll see this, but in your answer you forgot to swap cols and rows. So for anyone who wants to use this, it should be for x in range(rows), y in range(cols)